# How to write destructor when i have pointers in class?

Tags: c++, gtk

```
using namespace std;

class WINDOW
{    
    protected:
    GtkWidget *window;

    public:
    WINDOW();
    GtkWidget* get_window();
    void set_window(GtkWidget* w);
    void set_title(string s); 
    void show_widget_all();
    static void main_loop();
};
```

Comment: Does the object own the pointer (ie does it create it in the constructor)? Because you have badly defined set_window() method it is imposable to tell if your object owns the pointer. Thus it is imposable to know if your object should tidy up the pointer. You need to read about ownership semantics and define your methods so that ownership is explicitly expressed as part of your interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case just do

```
window = NULL;
```

Do

```
delete window;
window = NULL;
```

in the class where you created the object. This rule helps avoiding bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Point 1: In classes that have pointers you "just write the destructor" to clean up the resources allocated by you, there's nothing special with them.

Point 2: There is no need to do `delete window;` or anything similar since when `gtk_main()` exits it will destroy the window for you.

Point 3: Why don't you use Gtkmm since you are using Gtk+ in C++?