# In C++, how to write a destructor for freeing memory of pointer to a structure?

Tags: c++, struct

Here's my structure A

```
struct A {
    int a1;
    int a2;
    ~A() { }
};
```

`B` is another structure that contains a pointer to A

```
 struct B {
    B(int b, A* a)
      : b1(b), ptr2A(a)
    {}
    int b1;
    A* ptr2A;

    ~B() {
         delete b1;
         // traverse each element pointed to by A, delete them <----
    }
};
```

Later on I use below code

```
int bb1;
vector <A*> aa1;
// do some stuff
B *ptrB = new B(bb1, aa1);
```

I need to delete/free all the memory pointed to by ptrB. Hence I need to write correct destructor inside struct B. How do I traverse each element pointed to by A and delete them?

Comment: You need a C++ book. You're trying to mix and match things from `C` and trying to `delete` automatic variables. Further, there is nothing to traverse in `A` - you just `delete ptr2A`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write destructor when i have pointers in class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317735/how-to-write-destructor-when-i-have-pointers-in-class)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using a C++11 compiler, just use std::shared_ptr and you don't have to worry about deletes. This is because the shared_ptr is a "smart" pointer that will automatically delete what its pointing to.

```
#include <memory>
struct B 
{
    int b1;
    std::shared_ptr<A> ptr2A;
    B(int b, std::shared_ptr<A> a):b1(b),ptr2A(a)({}
    ~B(){} //look ma! no deletes!
};
```

Use a shared pointer whenever you allocate something:

```
#include<memory>
...
{
    ....
    std::shared_ptr<B> ptrB( new B(bb1, aa1) );
    //Here is another, more readable way of doing the same thing:
    //auto ptrB = std::make_shared<B>(bb1,aa1);
    ...
}
//no memory leaks here, because B is automatically destroyed
```

[Here's more info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) on the subject of smart pointers.

I should also mention that if you don't have a C++11 compiler, you can get shared pointers from the [BOOST library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Introduction).

Comment: Sorry. I took long to type. I have added details to the question. I use the new operator later on

Comment: Thanks! So you mean I just need to do a `delete ptrB` and it will all be taken care of?

Comment: As long as you use smart pointers, you don't need to do deletes. There are various types of smart pointers, but start off with the shared_ptr for now.

Answer (score 7):

You've only got one pointer to `A`. So you only need to delete that:

```
~B() {
     delete ptr2A;
}
```

Note that you can't `delete` b1, since it's a plain `int`! (The memory taken up by the variables of the structure, such as `b1` and the pointer `ptr2A` itself (not what it points to) are destroyed automatically along with any instances of that structure.)

Comment: Sorry. I took long to type. I have added details to the question. I use the new operator later on

Answer (score 7):

You need only to `delete` objects allocated by `new`.  In this case there's no need to delete `b1` as it has not been dynamically-allocated. Moreover, if you did not initialize `ptr2a` with dynamic memory, deleting it is undefined behavior.

So there's no need to worry about deleting `A`s data as it will be destructed from memory along wih the instance of the class.

Comment: Sorry. I took long to type. I have added details to the question. I use the new operator later on.

Comment: All you need to do is use `delete ptrB` when you're done using the memory it points to. Don't do that inside the class, do it inside main where you defined it.

Comment: Ah. I was under the impression that the code `delete ptrB` will call destructor of B. So we have to do it (freeing memory pointed to by `aa1`) inside destructor of B.