# C++ : dynamic memory allocation , copy constructor and delete

Tags: c++

As I am using pointers member variables in my code , I had to create a dynamic memory allocation . But when i tried to delete the allocated memory space I, the compiler crashes and I have no idea ..why??

```
//Class definition

Class A{
private:
int max_abc; //size of array of classes p_abc
B* p_xyz; //B is some other class type
C ** p_abc; //C is some other class type
public:
A(int max_xyz =2, int max_abc =2);
A(const A & Copy); //copy constructor
~A();
}

//and my constructor is as below

A::A (int max_abc )
{
p_abc= new C*[max_abc]; //dynamic memory allocation

p_xyz= new B;
}

//copy constructor - I had to do deep copy
A:: A(const A & copy)
{
max_abc = copy.max_abc;

p_xyz= new B;
p_xyz= copy.p_xyz;

m_abc = new C*[max_abc];
for(int j=0;j<max_abc;j++)
{
m_abc [j] = new C;
m_abc [j] = copy.m_abc[j];
} 
}

//destructor definition

~A()
{
delete [] p_xyz;
for(int j=0;j<max_abc;j++)
    {
    delete m_abc [j];
    } 
    delete [] m_abc ;
}
```

I seriously dont understand , why my compiler is crashed . Could some one please let me know, if my above definitions are correct\or reason for compiler crash ?? Please help....Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your compiler crashed, or the application, that you compiled, crashed? Those are 2 separate things. And I seriously doubt that your compiler would crash in any circumstances.

Comment: `new []` -> `delete []`. `new` -> `delete`. Never mix.

Comment: Take a look at this and see if this solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993791/in-c-how-to-write-a-destructor-for-freeing-memory-of-pointer-to-a-structure

Comment: `p_xyz= new B; p_xyz= copy.p_xyz;` in copy constructor. Not to mention that this code creates a memory leak (you allocate the memory for `B` object, and immediately overwrite the address to allocated space), you just copy pointer to `B`, which in turn, leads to multiple deallocations of the same memory block,when both destructors are called, leading to UB.

Comment: Good on you to follow the Rule of Three, though. Full props.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The OP may be using Visual Studio in which case I totally believe their compiler would crash! ;)